Axios catches 500 Error from response in success interceptor
I integrate with some api, and when the response has some error status, like 401 or 500, it lands anyway in the success interceptor and not error. Is it normal behaviour? Is there maybe the problem with the backend?

Do you handle the error using catch ? :
axios.get('example.org').then((res)=>...).catch((e)=>...)

yes I do, But it doesnt matter cause first the response goest through interceptor and then goes to then or catch block

You need to handle the error inside the middleware:
e.g.
const myHTTPClient = axios.create();
myHTTPClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
         // error handling
    }
)

